# Configuring emblem with yeoman

Tags: ember.js, yeoman, emblem.js

I have created an ember project using yeoman. I am trying to add emblem.js for templating as opposed to the handlebars but I am not able to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

My config for Gruntfile looks like this:

```
emblem: {
          compile: {
            files: {
              ".tmp/scripts/compiled-templates.js": ['app/templates/**/*.{emblem,hbs,hjs,handlebars}']
            },
            options: {
              root: 'app/templates/',
              dependencies: {
                jquery: 'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
                ember: '',
                handlebars: '',
                emblem: ''
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I also changed my emberTemplates configuration to:

```
emberTemplates: {
                files: '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/*.{emblem,hbs,hjs,handlebars}',
                tasks: ['emberTemplates']
            }
```

Comment: You haven’t given enough information for anyone to help. What’s going wrong? How did you try to add Emblem? By the way, I recommend ember-cli over yeoman.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show what my Gruntfile looks like for emblem configuration.